# Canon IIIa Batteries

Tags: 35mm, film-cameras

What batteries do Canon IIIa cameras need? Or do they need any? I've never used a film camera before. I've tried googling but all that comes up is about DSLRs.

Comment: Good luck Holly, a great camera, I cut my teeth with a Leica iiif, with some fantastic canon Serenar ltm....I think these types of cameras without any crutches are the best way to really deepen your photo knowledge, keep in mind the sunny 16 rule and start really seeing the light and thinking in EV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this one from 1952?

From [Canon IIIA, IVF, IVS Rangefinder Cameras of 1952](https://www.canonrangefinder.org/Canon_IIIA_IVF_IVS.htm)

[image]

Batteries in those days would have been nearly the size of the camera. You can be pretty sure nothing of that vintage is ever going to need batteries, except for a [flash](https://www.canonrangefinder.org/Canon_IIAF_IIAX.htm),

[image]

which wouldn't really be on rangefinder cameras for another few years.

Comment: Yeah that's it thank you

Comment: Tetsujin don’t forget that all the manual focus that had a meter used tiny mercury cell batteries pretty much the same size as today's coin batteries like the cr 22 small electronics, watch...

Comment: Granted the iiia doesn’t have a meter so it doesn’t need batteries